# **Simplification Challenge in Mathematical Proof Involving Musielak–Orlicz Function and Doob Maximal Operator**

Tags: measure-theory

I'm working on a mathematical proof and have encountered a step that I'm struggling to simplify. The expression is given by:

\begin{align*}
&= \frac{t}{\mathbb{P}(B)^{\lambda+1}}\int_{B} \varphi(x,\mathbf{1}_{B\cap {M(f)>t}}) \, d\mathbb{P}(x) \\
&= \frac{t}{\mathbb{P}(B)^{\lambda+1}} \int_{B\cap{M(f)>t}} \varphi(x,1) \, d\mathbb{P}(x) \\
&= \frac{t}{\mathbb{P}(B)^{\lambda+1}} \int_{B\cap{M(f)>t}}  \, d\mathbb{P}(x).
\end{align*}

I have a Musielak–Orlicz function $\varphi$ satisfying conditions $(\textrm{A}0), (\textrm{A}1)$,$\mathrm{(aInc)}_p$, and $(aDec)_p$, where $B \in \mathcal{A}(\mathcal{F}_n)$, $n \geq 0$, and $t \leq 1$. Additionally, I've used the Lemma \ref{Lemma 3.7.3} that introduces $\psi \in \Phi_s(\Omega, \mu)$ such that $\varphi \simeq \psi$ and $\psi(x, 1) = \psi^{-1}(x, 1) = 1$ for $\mu$-almost every $x \in \Omega$.
and Denoting the Doob maximal operator by $M$, the conditional expectation operators with respect to $\{F_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$ are represented as $\{E_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$. For any $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $f\in L^1(\Omega)$,

$
E_n(f) = \sum_{A\in\mathcal{A}(F_n)}\left[\frac{1}{P(A)}\int_A f\,dP\right]1_A\tag{2.3}.
$

The Doob maximal operators $M_n$ and $M$ are defined for any measurable function $f$ as

$
M_n(f) = \sup_{0\leq k\leq n}|E_k(f)| \quad \text{and} \quad M(f) = \sup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}|E_n(f)|.
$
I'm trying to simplify the expression to show that:

$
\frac{t}{\mathbb{P}(B)^{\lambda+1}}\int_{B} \varphi(x,\mathbf{1}_{B\cap {M(f)>t}}) \, d\mathbb{P}(x) \leq \frac{t}{\mathbb{P}(B)^\lambda} \leq 1.
$

Any guidance on how to proceed with this simplification would be greatly appreciated.